# Application Error for Heroku Deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

I am deploying a website on Heroku, but I received the "Application Error" when I try to run "heroku open".

I believed I have successfully pushed the files into Heroku, part of my code for "git push heroku master":

```
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Ruby version change detected. Clearing bundler cache.
       Old: ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
       New: ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-linux]
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
```

When I run "heroku config -s | grep PATH", I got

```
PATH=bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

I am using Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 4.0.0

```
heroku run ruby -v


Running `ruby -v` attached to terminal... up, run.1868
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-linux]
```

```
heroku logs


2013-09-03T22:19:50.190493+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 46820 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-09-03T22:19:51.029933+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
2013-09-03T22:19:52.871354+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-09-03T22:19:52.847082+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-09-03T22:19:55+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-09-03T22:23:34.575156+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy e565e1b by ...@yahoo.com
2013-09-03T22:23:34.607019+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by ...@yahoo.com
2013-09-03T22:23:35.309375+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-09-03T22:23:35+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-09-03T22:23:41.313490+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 13563 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-09-03T22:23:42.552501+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
2013-09-03T22:23:44.083113+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-09-03T22:23:44.076683+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-09-03T22:24:22.581967+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=b....herokuapp.com fwd="72.130.178.212" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T22:24:30.920322+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `ruby -v` by ...@yahoo.com
2013-09-03T22:24:36.331638+00:00 heroku[run.9757]: Awaiting client
2013-09-03T22:24:36.372167+00:00 heroku[run.9757]: Starting process with command `ruby -v`
2013-09-03T22:24:38.01
5326+00:00 heroku[run.9757]: Process exited with status 0
2013-09-03T22:24:38.038684+00:00 heroku[run.9757]: State changed from starting to complete
2013-09-03T22:24:46.077364+00:00 heroku[run.9757]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-09-03T22:24:46.077053+00:00 heroku[run.9757]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Failed to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
2013-09-03T22:30:10.825474+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-09-03T22:30:15.552054+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 18743 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-09-03T22:30:16.375616+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
2013-09-03T22:30:17.730288+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-09-03T22:30:17.736961+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-09-03T22:30:25.745760+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Failed to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
2013-09-03T22:30:25.745760+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-09-03T22:34:18.513539+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=....herokuapp.com fwd="72.130.178.212" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T22:34:21.087888+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=....herokuapp.com fwd="72.130.178.212" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T22:34:18.237589+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=....herokuapp.com fwd="72.130.178.212" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T22:34:18.614842+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=....herokuapp.com fwd="72.130.178.212" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-03T22:35:46.726669+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-09-03T22:35:51.458659+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 43128 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-09-03T22:35:52.432152+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
2013-09-03T22:35:54.001899+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-09-03T22:35:54.011795+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-09-03T22:36:01.666290+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-09-03T22:36:01.665773+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Failed to launch the dyno within 10 seconds

...The rest are duplicated codes...
```

```
heroku run rake db:migrate


/usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'


gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'
gem 'rack-cache', :require => 'rack/cache'
gem 'dragonfly', '~>0.9.15'



group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.7'
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
    gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.0.0'
    gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
    gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.3.0', :require => false
    gem 'database_cleaner', github: 'bmabey/database_cleaner'   
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
    gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
```

**gem env**

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
     - /home/User/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

**bin/rails**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

**bin/bundle**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)
load Gem.bin_path('bundler', 'bundle')
```

**bin/rake**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rake'
Rake.application.run
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens with heroku when ruby version specified in bin files. Try to repace "#!/usr/bin/env ruby1.9.1" => "#!/usr/bin/env ruby" in 3 files:

```
bin/bundle
bin/rails
bin/rake
```

Comment: I have done this already, but it still does not work.

Plus, wouldn't the '#' sign comment this line out anyway?

Comment: Just want to make sure i did everything right. After I have replaced the line in the three files, then I can run "heroku run rake db:migrate" directly, right? Or, do i need to do anything else between the steps? I have tried to run "git push heroku" again but it returns "Everything is up-to-date."

Comment: Just recognized that I am supposed to run:

"git add ." and
"git commit -m "comments" "
before pushing the files up to heroku. 

It all works now, Thank you!