# Error with migrating database in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm following Michael Hartl's tutorial on learning web development with rails. When it comes to migrating the database the command:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

gives the following error

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.2675
/usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory
```

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and I have declared that in the Gemfile. I don't really understand what could be causing this error and any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you creating database by heroku run rake db:create ?

Comment: @Dheer that db:create gives the same error as db:migrate

Comment: check this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443456/windows-heroku-run-rake-dbmigrate-error-usr-bin-env-ruby-exe-no-such-file-o
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603426/application-error-for-heroku-deployment
Hope this is helpful for u.

Comment: @Dheer The first answer there fixed my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Most welcome SoSimple :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
 /usr/bin/env ruby
```

instead of

```
 /usr/bin/env ruby.exe
```

on following files of your app.

```
bin/bundle
bin/rails
bin/rake
```

and the exec

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```